# VS Code Github.com - Clear cut process for Git

Tags: git, github

Is there any useful clear cut process with source control via Git?
Seems like there's lots of ways of doing it out there so just decided to make our own for our enviro.

What I am trying to do is use VS code for dev and use Git for Source Control (i.e. create repo, push local code to repo, pull and clone repo and have it opened up in VS Code so when I am dev I can commit,merge etc.) and out of the box seems simple but have to keep trying commands multiliple times and still not sure if I get 100%. So far my steps to as I have tried are below and would appreciate any help to fix and tidy.

## Setup

## 1. Open up VS Code

## 2. Be in working directory

## Local source to repo

1. Create the remote repository, and get the URL such as https://github.com/youruser/somename.git
2. Set up local Git repo - In VS Code in terminal (at the root directory of your source) run: git init
3. Locally, add and commit what you want in your initial repo so e.g. for everything:
   git add . 
   git commit -m 'initial commit comment')
4. To attach your remote repo with the name 'origin' (like cloning would do)
   git remote add origin https://github.com/youruser/somename.git. If 'origin' is already taken then use something else e.g. origin 2
5. To push up your master branch (change master to something else for a different branch):
   git push -p origin master

   Or if different branch and not master: 
   git push -p origin BranchName

## To work with source control

Once repo created and available

1. Uploaded to it - via file upload - Push did not work so had to use upload in github.com
2. Push: git push -u origin master
3. Pull to branch local dir: git pull origin --all
4. Create new directory: mk,cd newDir
5. Clone to branch dir: git clone https://github.com/gitmasoud/azsearchdirectory/pull/new/azsearchdirectoryC1
6. Pull: git pull origin azsearchdirectoryC1 --allow-unrelated-histories
7. Clone - git clone https://github.com/gitmasoud/azsearchdirectory.git
8. Open branch - git branch azsearchdirectoryC1
9. Go to branch dir in VS's Explorer

## Not working so far (May or not be due to previous steps):

Not working so far (May or not be due to previous steps):

Now you can commit,compare,push etc

Any advice is greatly appreciated -

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: Ah sorry - When I commit in VS either nothing happens or it says you're in a Directory thus making no commits. I've tried staging then committing too.

Comment: @KidKode your original post isn't clear where you're having trouble. Can you update it? You say "Push did not work so had to use upload in github.com" Are you using the builtin version control for VS Code? Or are you using command line? A client? How are you committing in VS Code? In the activity bar you have the source control tab that opens up and you can see the files stagged or not.  You can hit "+" to stage the files and then run the >git commit from the command palette. Let me know the steps you are doing to commit in VS code.